# Should I use a single table for many categorized rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to implement some user event tracking in my website for statistics etc.
I thought about creating a table called `tracking_events` that will contain the following fields:

```
| id (int, primart) |
| event_type (int) |
| user_id (int) |
| date_happened (timestamp)|
```

this table will contain a large amount of rows (let's assume at least **every page view** is a tracked event and there are **1,000** daily visitors to the site).

Is it a good practice to create this table with the `event_type` field to differentiate between essentially different, yet identically structured rows?

or will it be a better idea to make a **separate table for each type**? e.g.:

### table `pageview_events`

```
| id (int, primart) |
| user_id (int) |
| date_happened (timestamp)|
```

### table `share_events`

```
| id (int, primart) |
| user_id (int) |
| date_happened (timestamp)|
```

***and so on for 5-10 tables.***

(the main concern is performance when selecting rows `WHERE event_type = ...`)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends.  If you need to have them separated, because you will only be querying them separately, then splitting them into two tables should be fine. That saves you from having to store an extra discriminator column.

BUT... if you need to query these sets together, as if they were a single table,  it would be much easier to have them stored together, with a discriminator column.

As far as `WHERE event_type=`, if there are only two distinct values, with a pretty even distribution, then an index on just that column isn't going to help much. Including that column as the *leading* column in a multicolumn index(es)  is probably the way to go, if a large number of your queries will include an equality predicate on that column.

Obviously, if these tables are going to be "large", then you'll want them indexed appropriately for your queries.

Comment: seems like **discriminator column** is the term I've been searching for (though it doesn't yield much relevant results in search either).
I edited the question to reflect there are more than just two distinct values for `event_type`.
So, if I understand correctly:

 - if I query only one type at a time, I'm better off using distinct tables.
 - otherwise, I should set the discriminator column as the first index column?

Comment: @Imashcha: If the rows in those table are entirely separate, then yes, I'd use two separate tables. If those are really subclasses of a superclass, then I'd lean towards the single table with the discriminator column. You'll find most discussion of "discriminator column" (that's what I call it) in discussions of ORM approaches to mapping a class hierarchy into a relational database structure... table per subclass, or single table for superclass with discriminator column. (I also use the term discriminator column for an expression added in UNION ALL queries, to tell which query returned a row)

Comment: My biggest hesitation with the separate tables is that you're going to wind up needing to run `UNION ALL` queries to combine rows from the two tables.

Comment: *They are* subclasses of a super class, but that doesn't imply they will be used together: Book A and Book B are both books - but will they ever necessarily be put together on the same shelf or in the same library?

Comment: @Imashcha: In terms of a database design, the question is if the *superclass* is important to your application, or will your application work with just the subclasses. (Book A and Book B are really exemplar instances of a class. I'm not very good at doing class hierarchies without some actual data, and usually the issue is differences in attributes... some example of subclasses might be "book I borrowed from the Library" and "book I purchased"... where some of the attributes (borrowed date, due date) apply to one subclass but not the other (price paid, purchased from).

Comment: I don't think the superclass should matter in the near future. Worst case scenario, I merge the subclasses into a big table. No?

How much of a performance difference are we talking about? If it isn't noticeable I guess splitting into small tables is not worth the effort.

Comment: My preference would be the separate tables; that gives me some degree of partitioning (more manageable-sized sets), and I don't need to muck with an extra column. What I don't want to get myself into is writing statements like in this question  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540082/too-many-results-showing-need-to-limit/30540492#30540492[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540082/too-many-results-showing-need-to-limit/30540492#30540492) , that have to combine results from queries multiple tables, and then order them, to present them back like they were all from one table.